# Landscape server quickstart and lxd problem

Tags: landscape, lxd

A bit leading up to my problem. I had a landscape server for personal use running on one server with nfs for my home directory. Was getting parts to upgrade that server and thought I would move the landscape server to my other server, which has backup nfs and runs lxd. First tried to get landscape-server-quickstart running in a xenial container, but could not get rabbitmq to install.

So here's my problem. I installed landscape-server on the second server and everything went fine. Registered my other computers to it just fine. When going to register my containers, that's where everything went wrong. I did:

```
$ lxc exec "containername" bash
error: not found
lxc list returns no containers.
```

They are running and working fine. Even after a reboot. One, I have ssh working on as a user, not root, and can ssh into it. As far as `lxc` is concerned they are not there.

Any help in getting my containers back would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the "lxc list" output please? Did you use apt to install it or snap ?

Comment: "lxc list" just shows column headers. Containers still running, even after reboot. Landscape-server-quickstart installed with apt. "lxd" was wiped 3 weeks ago from apt install and reinstalled from a snap. That went good. "sudo zfs list" shows everything is still in place. Creating a new container fails with error about no lxdbr0. I was using br0.

Comment: The snap of lxd was used for newer features.

Comment: Have you done "migration" from non snap to lxd snap?  Take a look on this discussion https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/migrate-from-ppa-to-snap/816

Comment: Did apt remove, purge and autoremove. Remove the lxd dataset. Manually got rid of the few remaining configs. Installed the snap of lxd. Everything worked tillI installed landscape-server-quickstart.

Comment: Assuming the containers are in /var/lib/lxd, all the directories are empty except "images". The files "server.crt" and  "server.key" are there, also with .